# Blender snapping tool

Tags: snapping, measurement

Can one snap the measurement tool to the blender grid? I have tried everything, but have had no luck. Is there a better plugin available on one of the marketplace places to use instead of the default measure tool?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can add a plane and snap it to the grid on resize with `Ctrl`. then you can snap the ends of the measurement tool by dragging it with `Ctrl` to snap it to any vertex on the plane.